# Splitting a set of complex ODE in real ODEs

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610087/numerically-solve-complex-differential-equation) it is stated that "Any n dimensional ODE system in $\mathbb{C}$ can be described as an 2$n$ dimensional ODE system in $\mathbb{R}$ using

$z(t)=\mathrm{Re}(z) + i \ \mathrm{Im}(z)$ and $t=\mathrm{Re}(t) + i\ \mathrm{Im}(t)$."

This shall be done by

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\mathrm{Re}(z)]}{\mathrm{d}[\mathrm{Re}(t)]} = \mathrm{Re}[f(z,t)]
$$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\mathrm{Im}(z)]}{\mathrm{d}[\mathrm{Im}(t)]} = \mathrm{Im}[f(z,t)]
$$

- **Is this procedure really general and without any additional requirements on $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t \in \mathbb{C}$?**
- **Can any use be made of a fact that the interval of integration in complex plane is a straight line?**